# Angular ng-repeat not updating after Notification Factory model changed internally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-services

In my Angular app, I have a simple notification factory which allows me to store and get information I want to convey to the user:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('peaches')
        .factory('NotificationFactory', factory);

    // factory.$inject = ['dependencies'];

    /* @ngInject */
    function factory() {

        var messages = [];

        var service = {
            postAlert: postAlert,
            getAlerts: getAlerts,
            deleteAlert: deleteAlert
        };

        return service;

        function postAlert(alert) {
            messages.push(alert);
            if (alert.duration) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    deleteAlert(alert);
                }, alert.duration)
            }
        }

        function getAlerts() {
            return messages;
        }

        function deleteAlert(alert) {
            messages.splice(messages.indexOf(alert), 1);
        }
    }
})();
```

As you can see in the `postAlert` function, I want to be able to delete a notification if said notification has a `duration` property, after `duration` number of milliseconds.

The intention is to have certain kinds of notifications automatically disappear after a number of seconds instead of requiring interaction to close.

This is a sample notification:

```
var reportSaved = {
    msg: "Report saved.",
    type: "success",
    duration: 1500
}
```

[image]

What's happening, however, is that even though `setTimeout` is working as intended and effectively deleting the notification after the set `duration`, the element is still drawn until I change page (after which it disappears as intended), so the `ng-repeat` is never updated after calling `deleteAlert` from within my factory.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="notification" ng-repeat="alert in vm.alerts(); track by $index" ng-cloak>
    <i ng-if="alert.type === 'notification'" class="fa fa-spinner"></i><i ng-if="alert.type === 'success'" class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> {{alert.msg}}
</div>
```

What's the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Try using `$timeout/$interval` instead of the native ones. Angulars wrapper will trigger a digest cycle when they run. Otherwise you can potentially end up in the situation where your model is changed but your view does not update. This could potentially be the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using angular $timeout instead of setTimeout. The difference is that $timeout runs digest cycle, which is needed for ng-repeat to update values.

Comment: This was it... Such a simple solution.